# What does γ mean before a gene name?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

I am reading the following [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/29190615/) and I have come across the following statement:

> It has been demonstrated that the phosphorylation of histone
> H2AX-Ser139 to form γH2AX.

I am not sure what the γ before the gene name H2AX means. Is γ used to indicate that H2AX is phosphorylated? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in this context $\gamma$ indicates phosphorylation. See e.g. "The phosphorylated form of H2AX is called $\gamma$-H2AX [18, 19]." from [here](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jna/2010/920161/), and references therein.

<s>I am unsure of the exact basis of this, but I believe that it is because the gamma phosphate group of a nucleotide triphosphate is the one that is generally used by kinases to phosphorylate other functional groups.</s> **SEE UPDATE for derivation.**

Other [notations such as the $p$ prefix](https://www.tocris.com/resources/peptide-nomenclature-guide) are more readable to me, but the usage appears to be cultural and somewhat field-specific.

**Update**

In response to @MattDMO comment, I read further and found that the terminology derives from [this paper](https://www.jbc.org/content/273/10/5858.short). They don't directly explain the terminology, but in context it's pretty clear:

> At the maximum, approximately 1% of the H2AX becomes $\gamma$-phosphorylated per Gy of ionizing radiation.

> In mammals, the serine in this motif is residue 139, the site of γ-phosphorylation.

> When mammalian cell cultures are exposed to ionizing radiation and the acid-soluble nuclear proteins are analyzed on two-dimensional AUT-AUC gels, novel components that will be referred to as $\gamma$ (Fig. 1, A and B) are found in the H2A region of these gels.

It appears that the name probably derives from an observation that was just "whatever in this 2-D gel is $\gamma$-P32 labeled when we induce DSBs when $\gamma$-P32 ATP is present."

@MattDMO also points out that the irradiation that induces the gamma component in this context is gamma radiation. So it's all a bit of a muddle, it could also be that.

Comment: I've never heard of $\gamma$ being used to denote phosphorylation except in the case of H2AX. I suspect the nomenclature derives from its discovery, probably as multiple isoforms by some sort of chromatography or gel electrophoresis, and the phosphorylated form was the third one named ($\gamma$ is the third letter of the Greek alphabet) or the third band/signal observed. This is just a guess, but an educated one. I don't think it has anything to do with the $\gamma-PO_4$ group.

Comment: @MattDMo Turns out we're both right- it is because of the $\gamma$ phosphate, but it is also H2AX-specific, if I read the paper that first described this correctly. Editing answer.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the paper, it's been helpful. After reading parts of it, especially the 4th paragraph of the results section, I think they called the novel components $\gamma$ because they appeared **after ionizing $\gamma$ irradiation**, which is the primary form of radiation emitted by $^{137}Cs$, which was the rad source used in these experiments. So, $\gamma$-H2AX is a phosphorylated form of H2AX observed after exposure to $\gamma$-irradiation. Actually, it's probably both $\gamma$ irradiation and $\gamma$-ATP.

Comment: Hm. a lot of gammas here...

Comment: Which is probably what the grad student doing the experiments thought when s/he was labeling the autoradiograms of their gels.

Comment: @MattDMo tNo i was wrong! P32 is a beta emitter. *sigh of relief*

Answer (score 0):

You're correct: the gamma denotes phosphorylation, as explained and used in [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18610740/)'s abstract

> H2AX is a variant of the H2A protein family, which is a component of the histone octomer in nucleosomes. It is phosphorylated by kinases such as ataxia telangiectasia mutated (ATM) and ATM-Rad3-related (ATR) in the PI3K pathway. This newly phosphorylated protein, gamma-H2AX, is the first step in recruiting and localizing DNA repair proteins.